Why is it being said that finding a suitable exponent for solving the rsa problem allows to factor the modulus?
Simple question about the rsa assumption. I read that finding the private exponent allowing to decrypt an instance allows to factor the modulus (if the exponent was found without factoring). But why ?

In RSA, the public key $(N,e)$ is assumed available. Thus the present question is equivalent to: why can we factor $N$ given $(N,e,d)$.
